# Why does my SASS @import, go onto my CSS @import?

Tags: css, import, compilation, sass

Ok so for example, lets say I have main.css, main.sass, about.sass, and contact.sass.

main.sass should have @import about.sass and @import contact.sass. Then, when main.sass is compiled, main.css should have all the content of about.sass and contact.sass. Not @import's.

Main.sass

```
@import 'tools/fonts' 
@import 'tools/normalize'
@import 'tools/grid'
```

Now when this is converted to main.min.css it looks exactly the same as in main.sass

```
@import url(tools/fonts.css);
@import url(tools/normalize.css);
@import url(1-tools/grid.css);
```

Shouldn't there be no @imports, just the combined css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files you are importing don't have names that start with an underscore. If the file starts with an underscore then SASS knows that it is a partial file, and should be included wherever it is imported.

If a file name does not start with an underscore, then it will be generated as it's own CSS file.

This behaviour is described [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials).

> Partials
>
> If you have a SCSS or Sass file that you want to import but don’t want to compile to a CSS file, you can add an underscore to the beginning of the filename. This will tell Sass not to compile it to a normal CSS file. You can then import these files without using the underscore.
>
> For example, you might have _colors.scss. Then no _colors.css file would be created, and you can do
>
> ```
> @import "colors";
> ```
>
> and _colors.scss would be imported.
>
> Note that you may not include a partial and a non-partial with the same name in the same directory. For example, _colors.scss may not exist alongside colors.scss.

Comment: Thank you very much